# Allow custom event handlers to prevent default action with deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jquery-deferred

The thing I'm trying to accomplish is as follows:

I have a link opening a popup, but because that popup allows editing data in a database record I want to check if the database record is locked before I open the popup. And if the database record is locked, a message should be shown to the user instead of the popup.

My idea was to trigger a custom event to allow any listener to stop the popup from opening, like:

```
$(".popuplauncher").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();  // Stop the default click action: opening the popup
  var myCustomEvent = $.Event("myCustomEvent");
  $(this).trigger(myCustomEvent);
  if (myCustomEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // Show message 'database object locked'
  } else {
    // Everything ok, open the popup
  }
});
```

But, since one the event listeners has some asynchronous behaviour (asking the server if the database object is locked), I think I should use deferred objects in the event listeners.

```
$.when($(this).trigger(myCustomEvent)).then(...)
```

won't work, since trigger() doesn't return a deferred object, it returns the JQuery object itself to allow for chaining.

```
$.when($(this).triggerHandler(myCustomEvent)).then(...)
```

doesn't do the trick either for me, as triggerHandler() only returns the value of the last event handler. So if I have more than one event handler, all but the last handler are ignored.

Am I on the right track here, or should I go for a different approach to this problem? If you ask me, I would say that this is a common issue. That's why I hope I overlooked an easy, ready to use solution.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDtEa/9/) I made while playing around with the `triggerHandler()` stuff. Please note that only the last handler/deferred matters.

Comment: seems like a long way around simply making an ajax call, then depending on status of return data, open popup with appropriate content within a success handler. If this is oversimplifying it...need a better explanation of higher level issue at hand

Comment: Actually, the code posted above is from a widget whose only job is controlling popups. The code for checking the database lock is (and should be) in a completely different module (separation of concerns). The main issue is allowing multiple asynchronous handler to cancel the default action. I can foresee other similar situations with multiple event handlers that are quite independent of the popup code in the future, that is why I need a general solution, not a dirty fix.